# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open in ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2, package.json

I was just creating a new project `ionic start blank --v2` and the i gave `ionic serve`. in my browse i am getting error like below

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/panini/myApp/www/index.html'.

this is my output for `ionic serve` in `cmd`

```
Running live reload server: http://localhost:35729
Watching: www/**/*, !www/lib/**/*, !www/**/*.map
√ Running dev server:  http://localhost:8100
Ionic server commands, enter:
  restart or r to restart the client app from the root
  goto or g and a url to have the app navigate to the given url
  consolelogs or c to enable/disable console log output
  serverlogs or s to enable/disable server log output
  quit or q to shutdown the server and exit

ionic $
```

I dont find any gulp file watch in my ionic serve

here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "ionic-hello-world",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.1.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.1.6",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "ionic-native": "2.2.3",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "0.6.21"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "0.0.43",
    "typescript": "2.0.6"
  },
  "description": "myApp: An Ionic project",
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": []
}
```

here is my ionic info result

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.3.0
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.2
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.0-beta.1
OS: Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS 
Node Version: v6.0.0
```

**Note**

According this https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/1420 discussion my script object in the package.json is not matching when i update with this below object it is working

```
"scripts": {
"build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
"watch": "ionic-app-scripts watch",
"serve:before": "watch",
"emulate:before": "build",
"deploy:before": "build",
"build:before": "build",
"run:before": "build"
}
```

**Question:**

> On giving ionic start myApp blank --v2 i am not able to generate package.json correctly.
>
> http://blog.ionic.io/improvements-to-ionic-build-process/ according to this blog i tried still no better output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was using ubuntu16.04 and i forgot to add the sudo command befor that was my issue while installing to latest one.

```
sudo npm install -g ionic@latest
sudo npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest
```

Now everything works fine

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing this same issue, I search here in ionic forum
 https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/1420 
Finally i came to relized that I have to do something like this-

I was missing index.html file here-
`www/index.html`
I just copy and paste index file to resolve this issue-
copy form `src/index.html`
paste here `www/index.html`

hopefully that will for for you as this worked for me.

> OR

another way to do is just update your local setup by following this  article
http://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/installation/

if you are getting error of node compatibility while installing cordova then just do it-

```
$ sudo npm install n -g
```

*to install n to manage node version.*

```
$ sudo n latest
```

*to install latest version of node.*

```
$ npm install -g ionic cordova
```

*to install cordova.*
   Now Create new app-

```
$ ionic start cutePuppyPics
```

run server-

```
$ cd cutePuppyPics
$ ionic serve
```

Hope it will help too...

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the exact same issue. I updated ionic to reflect this

cmd ionic info

```
Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.12
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7
ios-deploy version: 1.9.0 
ios-sim version: 5.0.11 
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v6.9.1
Xcode version: Xcode 8.1 Build version 8B62
```

**Note Node version is not 7.0**

Start a new project **sidemenu** or **tabs** and ionic -l or ionic serve should work.