# Why www folder is empty for application created using Ionic2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I Created a Ionic2 app using command:

ionic start rahul --v2

after that
cd rahul 
ionic serve

but it shows me error on browser:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/n/versions/node/7.0.0/rahul/www/index.html'

then i checked the www folder and i found there was nothing except one file named .gitkeep.

npm -v = 3.10.8 
node -v = v7.0.0 
cordova -v = 6.4.0 
ionic -v = 2.1.0-beta.3

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ionic-hello-world",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.1.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.1.6",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "ionic-native": "2.2.3",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "0.6.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "0.0.45",
    "typescript": "2.0.6"
  },
  "description": "jain: An Ionic project",
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": []
}
```

Comment: try to update your ionic cli and then  create a new one

Comment: This question is already posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40669878/error-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-open-in-ionic2

Comment: npm -v = 3.10.8, node -v = v7.0.0, cordova -v = 6.4.0, ionic -v = 2.1.0-beta.3

Comment: @Rahul check the question that i have asked in above comment there is a temporary solution for this problem, good luck

Comment: @mohan where is the temporary answer? and why temporary?

Comment: @Rahul check your package.json file and look on the script object in your current package.json and update it for more inforamtion please take a look athe github link and blog that i have posted

Comment: @Rahul, try @ionic/app-scripts with version 44 as mentioned in conference app. https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app/blob/master/package.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something was wrong with my Ionic2 installation.

here is the steps to install ionic2 if you have already installed ionic.
Update node
Update npm

then most important is update ionic and cordova simultaneously like:
**npm install -g ionic cordova**

What mistake i did is: I installed ionic and cordova one by one.

Answer (score 1):

update your package.json as below you so ionic serve will work
here `script` object is changed then everything worked as expected.
But i am still in research why it is not updating automatically.

take a look at this link http://blog.ionic.io/improvements-to-ionic-build-process/

```
{
  "name": "ionic-hello-world",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "watch": "ionic-app-scripts watch",
    "serve:before": "watch",
    "emulate:before": "build",
    "deploy:before": "build",
    "build:before": "build",
    "run:before": "build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.1.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.1.6",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "ionic-native": "2.2.3",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "0.6.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "0.0.45",
    "typescript": "2.0.6"
  },
  "description": "ionic1: An Ionic project",
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": []
}
```